# I am getting this error while integration Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am facing this error when I dispatch the action. I have used this method before it worked fine this time it constantly shows this error. Please Help I am unable to find any solutions on this. Thanks in advance.

Action:

```
export const listPackages = () => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({ type: PACKAGE_LIST_REQUEST })

    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/packages/all')

    dispatch({
        type: PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data  
    })

} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: PACKAGE_LIST_FAIL,
        payload: error.message && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
  }
}
```

My Reducer:

```
import {
PACKAGE_LIST_REQUEST,
PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS,
PACKAGE_LIST_FAIL
} from "../constants/packageConstants"

export const packageListReducer = (state = {packages: []}, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case PACKAGE_LIST_REQUEST:
        return {loading: true, packages: []}
    case PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return {loading: false, packages: action.payload}
    case PACKAGE_LIST_FAIL:
        return {loading: false, error: action.payload}
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

My Store:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension"

import {packageListReducer} from "./reducers/packageReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
packageList: packageListReducer,
})

const initialState = {}
const middleware = [thunk]
const store = createStore(reducer,initialState,composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

Component From Where I dispatched the action:

```
import {listPackages} from "../actions/packageActions"

export default function HomeScreen1() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const packages = []

  useEffect(() => {
dispatch(listPackages())
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: I've pored over this code for a while now and can't poke any holes in it. Is it all asynchronous actions that have an issue or this `listPackages` action specifically? Is there any more accompanying information with the error? An included stacktrace or similar?

Comment: This is not a solution but an alternative: Use [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to simplify the code to setup store, middlewares, actions, reducers etc.

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried different actions too. But getting same error.

Comment: I don't disagree with @AjeetShah, redux-toolkit makes configuring your redux store stupid simple and includes the thunk middleware by default. I still can't find fault in these code snippets, but can't see how you use the exported `store`. Can you update your question to include how you setup your app? Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox with ***your*** code that reproduces this issue that we can live debug/inspect?